# How would you remove trailing comma when writing to a stream json in node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, csv

Suppose I have code as below:

```
const fs = require('node:fs')
const csvParser = require('csv-parser')

const rs = fs.createReadStream(dir)
const ws = fs.createWriteStream(outDir)

ws.write('[' + '\n')
rs.pipe(
    csvParser({
      mapHeaders: mapper,
    }),
)
.on('data', (data) => {
      ws.write('\t' + JSON.stringify({ ...data, provider } + ',\n'))
})
.on('end', () => {
      ws.write(']')
      console.log('writing to a file has been completed >> ', OUT_DIR)
})
```

Basically what this code does is to read from large csv file then stream this into write a json file. As seen in the code, I append ',\n' as separator for each row such that all the json code is formatted once streaming has been completed.

The issue with such method is that it leaves comma at the end of each entry that you would have to manually format the file (i.e. removing trailing comma) each time document write is completed.

For instance, the result would come out be as such:

```
[
  {"key1":"value1", "key2":"value2"},
  {"key1":"value1", "key2":"value2"}, // <- note the trailing comma here. 
]
```

Any suggestion as to handling the trailing comma?
Also, what would be alternative way of handling read and write stream better, please let me know. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Basically add the comma before the data, and use a flag to indicate if it's the first record, and only add if it's not.  LOL, basically what Q has just posted.. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd reverse the problem and include the comma before every item except the first.

```
let first = true;
ws.write('[' + '\n')
// ...
.on('data', (data) => {
  if (!first) {
    ws.write(',\n');
  } 
  first = false;
  ws.write('\t' + JSON.stringify({ ...data, provider }))
})
```

Answer (score 0):

**[EDIT]**
as mentioned in comments, this defeats the purpose of using stream. Don't use this on really large files

I would not handle the trailling coma but here is how I would do it.
The idea is to push each row into an array and the `JSON.stringify()`thee whole array.

Something like this

```
const rows = []
rs.pipe(
    csvParser({
      mapHeaders: mapper,
    }),
)
.on('data', (data) => {
      rows.push({ row content })
})
.on('end', () => {
      ws.write(JSON.stringify(rows))
      console.log('writing to a file has been completed >> ', OUT_DIR)
})
```

Comment: This kind of defeats the purpose of using streams, doesn't it ?

Comment: This means having to hold the entire data set in memory at once, which defeats the benefits of using a stream.

Comment: Only problem then is it takes away the whole reason to pipe in the first place,  IOW: Save on memory, etc.  Eg.  If CSV parser is parsing Gigs of data, this will take gigs of ram..

Comment: Guys, you totally right

Answer (score -1):

There is probably a better way to do it but I would do something like this:

```
const fs = require('node:fs')
const csvParser = require('csv-parser')

const rs = fs.createReadStream(dir)
const ws = fs.createWriteStream(outDir)
let buffer = null;

ws.write('[' + '\n')
rs.pipe(
    csvParser({
      mapHeaders: mapper,
    }),
)
.on('data', (data) => {
      if (buffer) {
        ws.write(buffer + ',\n'))
      }
      buffer = '\t' + JSON.stringify({ ...data, provider })
})
.on('end', () => {
      ws.write(buffer + '\n'))
      ws.write(']')
      console.log('writing to a file has been completed >> ', OUT_DIR)
})
```

Comment: `if (buffer) {`  when will this ever be false?

Comment: Updated the answer, my bad. Other answer is better anyway :)